# restructuredtext: what is the best way of extracting bibliographic and other fields?

Tags: python, restructuredtext

I am putting together a website where the content is maintained as restructuredtext that is then converted into html. I need more control than e.g. rst2html.py, so I am using a my own python script that uses things like

```
docutils.core.publish_parts(source, writer_name='html')
```

to create the html.

publish_parts() gives me useful parts like the title, body, etc. However, it seems I must look elsewhere to get the values of rst fields like

```
:Authors:
:version:
```

etc. For this, I have been using publish_doctree() as in

```
doctree = core.publish_doctree(source).asdom()
```

and then going through this recursively using using getElementsByTagName() as in

```
doctree.getElementsByTagName('authors')
doctree.getElementsByTagName('version')
```

etc.

Using publish_doctree() to extract fields does the job, and that's good, but it does seem more convoluted than using e.g. publish_parts(). 
My question is simply whether this is the best recommended way of extracting out these rst fields, or is there a more direct and less convoluted way? If not, that is fine, but I thought I would inquire in case I am missing something.

Comment: I think you can override the writer class and have your hook there which collects stuff to your internally maintained list when publish_doctree() runs. Never done this myself, though, so idea about the details.

Comment: See visit node: http://wiki.python.org/moin/ReStructuredText

Comment: Thank you. [the page you mentioned](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ReStructuredText) is very useful. They say there that "There's documentation on how to read reST, and output an entire HTML document. But if you want just a fragment of HTML, there's almost nothing. " That's been my experience too. It is surprising given that restructuredtext seems to be used a lot.

Comment: In that case please feel free to update the wiki page with your solution when you have one so we have nothing plus one solutions :)

Comment: Good idea. I hope I will be able to provide some help.